# play framework - securesocial userpass implementation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I'm using Play 2.1 and securesocial master snapshot.

I've implemented find & save of UserService (extends UserServicePlugin) as follows:

Find method as below:

```
 def find(userId: UserId): Option[Identity] = {
    val user = User.findByUserId(userId);
    user match {
      case Some(user) => {
        val socialUser = new SocialUser(userId, null, null, user.name, Option(user.email), Option(user.photo), AuthenticationMethod("userPassword"), null, null, Some(PasswordInfo(PasswordHasher.BCryptHasher, BCrypt.hashpw(user.password, BCrypt.gensalt(10)))))
        Option(socialUser)
      }
      case None => {
         None
      }
    }
  }
```

Save method as below:

```
 def save(user: Identity): Identity = {
    user.id.providerId match {
      case "facebook" => {

      }
      case "google" => {

      }
      case "twitter" => {
      }

      case "userpass" => {
        val eUser = User.findByEmail(user.id.id) match {
          case Some(eUser) => {
            //Existing User - update only
          }
          case None => {
            val appUser: User = new User(NotAssigned, "student", user.id.providerId, user.fullName, user.id.id, user.passwordInfo.get.password, null, null, null, null, null, "active")
            User.create(appUser)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    user
  }
```

When saving (signup) the password is being encrpted into the database, I'm not sure whether it should be encrypted or not and the above always says "The credentials you entered are not valid."

But if I use the word "password" (String) instead of user.password (from database) in find method like below it valids the credentials correctly, and logs me in:

```
    val socialUser = new SocialUser(userId, null, null, user.name, Option(user.email), Option(user.photo), AuthenticationMethod("userPassword"), null, null, Some(PasswordInfo(PasswordHasher.BCryptHasher, BCrypt.hashpw("password", BCrypt.gensalt(10)))))
```

Here I think it is again trying to encrypt the password from the database (which is already encrypted) ... I guess, I should either save the password without encrypting or get the password entered by the user in login page to use in find method. Could anyone please help me, thanks.

I believe the following are the two entry points for all Social Networks & the UserPass provider!

## Providers entry points

GET     /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticate(provider)

POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticateByPost(provider)

I think these implementations comes with the securesocial plugin? or should be replicate the same? Is it the best solution!!

I'm using MySQL and the below is my table:

```
create table t_users (
    id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    user_type enum('admin', 'user') not null default 'user',
    login_type set('userpass', 'facebook', 'google', 'twitter') not null default 'userpass',
    name varchar(64) not null,
    email varchar(128) null,
    password varchar(128),
    mobile varchar(10) null,
    facebook varchar(64) null,
    google varchar(64) null,
    twitter varchar(64) null,
    photo varchar(128),
    status enum('registered', 'active', 'suspended', 'deleted') not null default 'registered',
    modified timestamp not null,
    last_login timestamp not null,
    primary key (id),
    unique(email),
    unique(facebook),
    unique(google),
    unique(twitter)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `BCrypt.checkpw(suppliedPassword, hashedPassword)` somewhere.

So yes, you should be saving the hashed password to the database. Then when a user supplies a password on your login screen you should retrieve the hashed password for the user from your database, call checkpw, then if it returns true then log the user in.

Comment: `POST    /authenticate/:provider     securesocial.controllers.ProviderController.authenticateByPost(provider)` The above line is the default implemenation Authentication of the UserPass? Is it? If so, are you saying should we update or replace this with the above checkpw method?

Comment: SecureSocial should automatically do all the hashing for you. So it looks like your find() method is wrong. In your code it looks like you're hashing an already hashed password.

You should be able to copy the demo project and modify as necessary to get started: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples/scala/demo

Comment: I saw the sample, they are not using password or bcrypt or anything, but I found the issue, I'm trying to crypt the password again like `BCrypt.hashpw(user.password, BCrypt.gensalt(10))` which actually should be just `user.password` I dont know why I was doing that :(

Thanks for the discussion :) I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct find method as below:

```
 def find(userId: UserId): Option[Identity] = {
    val user = User.findByUserId(userId);
    user match {
      case Some(user) => {
        val socialUser = new SocialUser(userId, null, null, user.name, Option(user.email), Option(user.photo), AuthenticationMethod("userPassword"), null, null, Some(PasswordInfo(PasswordHasher.BCryptHasher, user.password)))
        Option(socialUser)
      }
      case None => {
         None
      }
    }
  }
```